# how to highlight a svg map image based on form

Tags: javascript, html

am new to coding, i have a form in my website that has a pickup and destination inputs, after the user submits the form it shows a svg map image , i want to highlight the the pickup and destination areas based on what's in the form through javascript maybe?, i searched for hours for how to do this but all i found is highlighting a map on hover and other useless stuff for me, please help. here's the form to show what i mean.

```
<form action="rideHandler.php" method="POST" id="tripinfo">
                
                    
                 <div id="toFrom">
                      <label>From?
                      <select name="from" id="from" required >
                          <option value selected disabled>select an area</option>
                          <option value="blahbalh">blahblah</option>
                          //other options
                      
                      </select>
                      </label>


                      <label>To?
                      <select name="to" id="to" required >
                          <option value selected disabled>select an area</option>
                          <option value="blahblah">blahblah</option>
                           //other options
                          
                      </select>
                      </label><br>
                 </div>
                   //other irrelevant form inputs
                      
               <button type="submit" class="subBtn" id="show"> Finish up</button>
```

ideally after submitting it shows a page with the highlighted areas, please help? i don't want code, i just want the method, how should i do it? and what should i use? should it be through javascript or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an example of the SVG you could show us? The best way that I could think to do this would be to use JS to highlight a known section of the map. You can tag the path you want to highlight with an id, and then use Javascript to select that path and change any property it has. Small demo below:

```js
function highlight() {
    document.getElementById("britain").style.fill = 'red';
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onClick="highlight()">Click me to highlight area!</button>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   height="1941.5708"
   width="1064.0363"
   version="1.1">
  <path
     id="britain"
     d="m 480.40861,432.95371 c -1.166,0.106 -1.89,1.416 -2,5.219 12.047,9.749 -3.062,6.258 -9.719,7.125 -5.957,-0.347 -6.754,-5.604 -15.906,-3.344 -10.007,10.509 -21.525,12.454 -34.625,10.438 -2.634,-14.556 -4.796,7.983 -12.813,-0.375 -3.609,6.989 -8.073,1.084 -11.219,7 -0.209,0.324 -14.297,-3.93 -18.124,6.625 -1.732,8.566 -9.646,13.053 -3.594,1.219 15.048,-10.29 -18.143,-25.705 -13.375,-10.188 -7.76,4.881 -9.621,16.34 -16.75,18.313 4.506,-9.193 16.232,-20.698 1.719,-24.344 -4.667,-10.497 -0.813,-0.383 -6.376,1.875 -1.77,-9.049 -12.039,-8.776 -19.031,-12.031 -1.758,4.176 0.06,9.418 -2.187,13.562 -8.995,6.206 -10.92,17.581 0.781,19.406 8.348,8.091 -8.682,-1.769 -7.5,6.969 -2.017,1.05 13.682,9.437 0.969,4.875 -6.734,-7.606 -9.85,14.695 -5.469,13.969 -5.007,7.775 19.732,13.786 17.25,13.844 1.428,6.653 -1.525,0.388 -7.156,0.25 -7.218,-6.528 -9.842,2.145 -16.594,0.343 -7.857,7.44 -15.297,-4.256 -19.25,1.032 5.824,6.238 7.203,16.219 15.75,18.187 -3.992,3.8 -0.631,4.129 -3.563,6.75 7.362,9.437 -5.796,6.048 -9.624,8.281 -3.519,-10.763 -14.562,-4.192 -5.844,3.094 4.845,5.41 13.807,14.144 23.344,18.156 -4.856,6.958 3.062,10.317 9.468,15.532 4.882,12.678 0.03,1.554 -6,-1.625 -5.012,-8.557 -15.021,-2.374 -18.125,-10.25 -12.062,-0.805 0.444,6.524 5.438,10.875 13.731,6.703 -3.083,5.412 -6.844,-2.313 -11.419,-11.123 -6.837,15.31 -18.344,3.719 -0.1,-8.857 -10.365,-14.352 -11,-2.938 2.615,4.91 10.272,15.814 4.657,17.969 -1.291,2.742 -3.369,5.807 -6.313,-2.937 0.06,-12.199 -5.568,-11.981 -15.125,-10.844 1.632,8.404 -3.67,26.385 10.469,25.75 8.899,10.395 -6.121,0.613 -7.5,7.656 -8.413,9.317 5.9,9.919 6,19.188 4.854,3.347 4.109,7.176 14.906,5.5 14.796,5.807 -11.812,0.644 -6.844,6.656 -4.664,0.886 -5.926,-8.833 -10.406,-6 -9.366,-15.542 -13.913,8.182 -11.469,18.656 7.481,0.295 5.114,6.635 5.094,10.938 -2.445,13.562 14.662,3.934 19.594,-2.406 -6.122,13.233 10.997,6.811 15.75,-2.376 3.6,4.868 -12.977,15.082 -21.094,14.376 -14.562,9.548 3.57,13.201 12.281,11.093 3.441,4.159 15.447,9.317 14.281,10.75 -9.52,-0.57 -13.19,-13.44 -23.187,-5.406 0.769,6.37 -1.323,10.109 -5.313,16.875 5.905,2.95 14.17,4.777 16.969,10.25 13.438,-3.871 2.658,3.768 -4.406,0.75 -6.881,-13.218 -29.93,2.851 -18.813,11.5 10.408,-5.924 3.945,11.344 15.126,8.062 14.523,-5.034 0.384,3.476 -6.063,2.376 -5.359,-5.236 -17.001,-11.816 -18.406,0.874 -3.713,5.561 -0.541,12.747 -3.438,13.813 -12.717,4.411 9.121,2.371 14.875,2.031 -11.341,3.424 1.295,9.858 4.469,1.406 4.307,7.919 -17.152,4.331 -17.281,11.938 10.844,2.849 6.288,8.69 -0.782,7.125 -1.437,0.239 -2.901,8.364 -8.906,0.344 -8.86,2.758 -21.95,0.578 -27.812,8.156 l 0.06,0 c -1.5,13.932 19.742,6.125 26.969,8.906 9.055,5.32 15.726,-5.304 24.031,-4.593 4.864,6.461 24.951,0.45 8.75,5.5 -9.451,-4.911 -16.94,-2.51 -24.281,4.937 -17.106,-6.22 -13.544,11.669 -2.25,18.281 10.867,2.312 12.405,2.725 19.844,8.469 13.078,0.934 19.738,-22.809 29.875,-25.687 3.883,-9.414 12.491,-9.409 15.531,-17.219 0.271,-3.092 14.643,-18.599 11.531,-11.375 -6.176,7.834 -17.67,20.839 -0.406,20.937 12.634,-7.222 1.654,4.886 -5.5,0.03 -12.038,0.555 -10.365,8.04 -16.531,13.094 -5.112,5.778 -8.196,19.703 2.687,13.25 13.033,-6.437 3.161,1.923 -3.5,4.5 -7.647,-7.396 -13.326,13.606 -7.031,3.5 1.857,3.356 4.876,7.824 10.75,6.656 17.317,2.567 -7.257,0.97 -11.344,0.938 -5.858,11.808 -15.697,20.2 -15.343,34.906 1.029,6.544 6.542,7.803 0.437,15.125 -6.363,14.276 1.811,5.71 6.5,-1.781 3.503,3.265 -8.209,14.272 -0.875,18.125 -9.306,-2.475 -10.817,11.94 -16.875,18.906 -1.267,14.28 2.937,0 6.969,-5.062 9.151,-13.826 4.181,4.3 -4.188,11.5 -6.076,11.175 3.441,10.264 8.438,2.187 1.683,2.798 -14.45,17.217 -5.875,25.406 5.759,9.824 13.217,-3.343 18.75,-10.156 -0.71,9.234 -15.496,17.488 -19.313,28.344 -3.813,10.707 -7.635,25.40999 -6.094,38.90599 -2.943,9.616 -13.742,16.174 -10.25,28.813 10.092,5.934 34.454,-2.463 28.657,-17.094 -8.105,-4.694 -0.752,-7.046 1.156,-14.5 0.964,-7.544 6.704,-16.203 4.563,-20.96899 -4.166,-11.938 6.804,-25.785 15.843,-32.375 -6.644,-14.562 -13.888,-25.7 -13.156,-42.156 2.619,4.538 10.917,-0.143 13.25,-7.156 3.387,-13.821 21.337,-14.928 23.687,-28.657 1.982,-0.708 16.499,-11.325 13.594,-5.468 -12.632,3.451 -11.318,16.875 -22.281,20.625 -8.394,7.493 -18.613,19.951 -18.5,31.25 -2.654,11.021 3.289,21.217 14.406,23.156 -4.206,-8.645 -1.107,-14.723 0.938,-23.375 0.553,3.544 16.708,17.894 10.156,2.031 3.705,-9.977 1.739,15.781 8.437,16.594 7.149,-3.378 10.048,-20.51 8.532,-23.781 4.88,-0.6 4.204,-16.797 1.656,-22.375 1.098,-17.146 0.731,12.424 7.062,-0.594 1.56,1.511 -9.007,17.026 -0.656,23.625 14.538,4.21 1.224,-6.581 0.719,-13.188 6.335,5.417 16.802,21.879 30.875,22.344 8.221,3.926 -13.581,-0.684 -18.375,-0.781 -15.332,-12.417 -22.329,10.218 -18.375,23.375 11.092,9.173 -9.739,18.983 4.844,23.969 2.352,9.312 20.445,8.03 18.094,21.24999 0.65,2.138 9.168,11.134 3.031,18.593 -12.514,1.582 -12.259,14.442 -19.781,21.376 2.373,16.586 -12.668,24.841 -18.188,37.25 -7.456,12.097 -2.612,24.538 3.344,34.968 -12.867,6.174 -3.306,-21.423 -16.032,-16.656 -11.878,13.156 4.582,32.862 13.407,42.562 8.978,5.692 0.323,19.764 13.531,22.719 2.514,-2.256 -0.621,-11.711 -4.219,-17.187 -6.568,-9.917 -4.047,-18.896 8.281,-22.656 5.548,3.21 13.714,9.984 21.313,13.218 7.582,6.789 12.57,18.013 24.781,18.188 6.245,-3.759 -1.898,-15.902 3.188,-18.782 -3.146,-6.294 -13.044,-12.567 -5.282,-20.124 2.142,-0.105 5.618,13.091 14.063,11.25 7.945,-10.747 2.498,4.383 8,7.468 8.07,9.09 8.733,1.094 12.031,-7.031 -3.248,9.544 5.317,16.714 13.25,8.594 11.281,-4.71 5.615,-8.281 9.532,-14.969 -0.457,1.79 4.243,5.786 11.5,-0.75 9.773,1.813 16.835,-1.37 13.874,-12.438 -2.962,-10.868 3.552,-2.298 6.063,-6.468 11.724,-0.806 31.239,7.634 46.063,0.531 12.993,-1.194 -9.948,7.257 1.343,5.281 -1.533,11.714 -19.173,-6.393 -24.75,6.125 5.793,2.547 2.148,10.673 -4.187,5.469 -4.427,-1.261 -12.579,14.493 -11.188,21.781 -13.079,10.705 -11.606,28.319 -18.625,41.344 3.255,14.21 24.49,25.88 22.157,42.687 2.418,6.901 13.772,21.085 16.437,9.719 3.023,-18.891 5.658,7.812 -0.156,9.157 -0.932,7.048 2.139,10.941 7.5,15.25 1.229,1.618 7.277,-7.685 10.156,-13.657 2.587,-12.504 4.911,-0.946 10.719,0.281 2.052,-3.462 17.046,-12.488 10.937,-5.593 8.283,10.728 1.559,16.764 -6.093,24.562 -0.145,9.123 7.644,4.59 4.812,12.031 3.354,5.156 -10.159,5.315 -16.906,6.719 -6.351,14.868 -5.517,43.36 17.812,32.375 -6.521,5.736 -21.6,15.874 -25.531,29.813 6.793,11.344 7.698,27.659 19.969,35.125 4.607,9.6 20.508,-3.469 15.406,6 -10.452,16.157 -25.691,-6.643 -27.125,-18.532 -21.254,-1.957 -14.932,15.171 -5.719,24.532 5.284,13.234 -5.397,4.096 -11.281,-1.594 -15.087,-21.837 -33.005,5.373 -51.25,0.344 -5.011,-3.469 -22.765,-13.104 -12.75,-1.063 -7.478,3.858 -22.312,11.858 -33.25,12.344 -4.995,4.815 -12.317,19.427 -16.375,17.969 0,9.79 -6.657,19.291 -15.656,25.75 -12.056,6.384 -22.615,14.612 -27.344,27.906 3.472,3.078 5.817,-3.137 10.938,-1.781 6.587,-8.405 11.638,6.722 15.937,1.969 -1.813,-13.947 16.855,-20.065 29.813,-19.157 13.589,3.869 -0.232,17.613 9.156,23.938 1.831,8.792 9.976,5.045 10.5,5.937 -10.017,5.125 -18.585,23.338 -4.469,30.188 10.354,-4.933 10.453,1.749 0.594,3.375 -5.144,3.156 -3.767,21.239 -9.344,29.625 -5.95,15.438 -21.627,19.874 -32.375,28.5 -3.961,9.189 -20.714,0.822 -24,8.281 -4.476,-0.169 -6.751,9.971 -14.312,11.281 1.635,9.967 -8.949,-0.04 -11.063,6.782 -2.708,-0.63 -16.166,-8.246 -13.5,2.656 -3.723,7.379 -16.626,8.387 -21.5,13.781 -5.317,11.92 11.158,0.185 17.437,8.437 4.63,10.229 -0.402,13.764 -7.687,17.594 -8.53,1.136 1.722,4.188 3,9.406 -0.08,-11.148 14.11,0.284 22,-4.25 16.337,-2.648 -5.944,5.52 -9.25,3.844 -2.843,1.263 -12.789,0.08 -1.719,4.438 -0.03,6.39 7.941,10.92 14.282,8.25 4.355,-9.229 15.237,-3.099 21.093,-8.406 -0.634,-14.972 16.484,-11.212 27.281,-13.188 -4.62,-9.907 2.383,0.416 5.376,-5.938 -0.374,3.434 11.111,11.851 1.437,8.126 -3.051,6.017 10.082,11.237 16.656,7.531 3.893,8.197 17.447,-3.756 11.313,5.375 -9.162,7.707 -15.332,-2.423 -20.906,6.281 -1.019,7.523 4.439,13.229 11.656,10.594 5.068,-4.973 13.894,-2.378 19.968,-2.781 -8.262,-8.378 11.357,-11.867 14.188,-7.969 9.154,4.788 6.079,23.556 16.969,21.656 11.025,16.213 33.533,18.189 49.531,11.031 -1.625,-11.281 11.335,-15.55 18.188,-23.656 4.875,4.708 17.332,0 25.156,-4.156 11.467,-7.216 18.157,-23.328 31.218,-27.719 3.917,-7.145 7.06,0.259 -0.437,2.031 -12.018,9.434 -19.743,25.336 -28.219,38.344 -11.218,0.442 -18.487,17.239 -25.281,19.469 -0.541,8.837 -6.439,7.297 -4.75,15.375 4.48,10.029 -2.992,16.295 -13.219,13.187 -11.912,6.112 -25.806,5.056 -36.281,-2.5 -9.769,1.347 -20.666,-2.799 -31.125,-0.75 -11.426,2.131 -35.481,-1.062 -38.719,8.969 -8.545,5.276 5.82,14.605 -4.562,21.5 -6.837,13.673 -18.263,1.076 -27.531,2.5 -0.09,5.312 0.06,10.764 -2.938,15.312 4.064,15.049 -3.046,25.281 -12.375,34.626 -11.1,1.758 -4.094,19.433 -18.313,17.624 -7.631,-1.162 -4.281,3.336 -7.874,4.938 -8.946,-2.161 -8.623,11.033 -11.126,20.656 -12.272,-0.508 -6.175,11.18 -15.281,15.875 -4.935,9.559 -17.391,10.933 -21.906,19.563 -8.074,-6.396 -16.05,2.319 -25.406,5.687 -3.337,4.816 -5.311,14.936 -0.469,18.563 15.472,6.418 11.133,-18.288 23.438,-11.75 15.125,0.844 18.192,14.195 24.343,24.125 2.25,-1.735 6.282,-8.903 11.719,-9 10.061,-7.285 -8.096,-11.571 0.406,-14.969 5.593,-5.5 0.03,-8.874 5.469,-15.344 0.947,-0.06 2.453,9.797 2.125,11.125 3.921,-6.512 7.865,-8.51 13.125,-12.375 9.906,0.652 9.847,-6.677 11.625,-13.531 1.662,-8.956 8.858,-0.29 11.375,-2.469 13.885,3.66 23.712,-8.812 37.656,-3.687 4.574,10.133 14.708,0.209 4.844,-1.875 11.605,-4.348 11.083,15.036 23.563,9.031 9.61,-4.062 12.677,14.912 20.718,12.656 8.265,3.974 14.49,-0.532 14.094,-10.437 6.819,-4.231 5.518,-11.067 11.125,-7.969 7.827,-8.868 -1.466,-7.626 -2.063,-16.406 11.149,-0.927 -1.093,-11.41 8.032,-17.813 7.072,-4.146 -3.991,-25.786 3.875,-13.218 4.972,15.381 14.434,-6.571 23.406,-6.532 15.517,2.231 29.25,-12.808 44.094,-2.375 11.289,7.824 32.583,15.437 29.719,30.563 1.704,-1.308 1.538,-4.09 3.5,-5.344 -5.079,-6.108 -3.176,-18.945 9.25,-13.812 14.117,-0.629 24.074,7.725 36.593,6 5.348,-5.418 3.772,-8.624 2.719,-13.25 -7.759,0.471 -8.108,-4.446 -12.469,-2.282 -4.982,-1.754 4.932,-5.109 9.907,-4.406 2.465,11.785 11.328,-6.524 20.624,0.469 0.98,-0.827 1.889,-5.929 9.844,-4.219 10.097,7.12 13.065,-1.118 22.219,-5.219 15.275,0.798 13.115,-12.639 2.969,-18.281 -14.523,-7.991 4.512,-1.873 8.375,4.75 6.435,2.003 16.167,17.709 20.25,8.188 -6.279,-6.306 -2.395,-7.939 4.812,-5.563 -8.594,6.32 3.451,14.848 3.75,1.781 9.068,-8.631 0.233,10.349 3.031,7.938 9.484,4.633 1.999,-17.723 7.563,-7.282 -0.82,0.509 11.109,-0.558 3.094,5.188 -5.87,3.023 17.105,16.512 14.093,5.531 3.879,-3.201 25.157,-5.242 35.813,-7.562 22.303,-10.163 44.018,5.92 65.031,10.093 8.012,-15.244 25.878,-15.4 40.844,-20.656 7.298,-12.52 18.995,-9.816 30.844,-6.937 -4.098,-14.779 10.134,-26.972 23.718,-27.907 11.612,-2.522 25.581,-12.321 19.219,-27.218 -7.836,-10.95 7.405,-10.108 5.188,-21.156 -3.353,-1.505 -7.468,0.212 -10.969,0.593 -18.681,-1.704 -35.909,11.544 -53.781,4.407 6.489,1.87 22.051,-3.226 7.343,-10.032 -7.14,-3.943 -14.824,-2.616 -15.156,1.063 -2.338,0.178 -2.678,8.519 -10.031,4.5 -12.114,2.41 -1.246,-10.642 6.469,-7.563 9.835,-5.797 -12.665,-9.658 -18.219,-7.844 -2.428,1.197 -14.78,10.007 -9.656,4.188 3.514,-10.863 16.836,-6.505 23.093,-11.656 9.321,1.924 20.456,1.04 27.032,-8.594 9.463,-7.334 -3.13,-4.311 -4.875,-3.469 -10.95,-7.303 3.792,0.854 7.343,-6.75 6.959,-10.512 -1.794,-20.215 -11.374,-11.343 -3.72,1.868 -9.531,2.339 -9.719,-2.782 13.039,2.946 14.769,-11.277 26.562,-11.531 6.084,11.043 21.536,3.879 27.594,-5.437 6.6,-10.983 -2.132,-0.371 -6.75,-5.626 4.01,-4.577 14.771,-13.347 0.656,-10.968 -11.879,1.585 -8.092,-5.029 0.813,-1.719 12.485,4.151 -2.099,-12.059 6.531,-4.187 4.335,16.195 14.798,-3.203 18.469,-10.844 12.892,-1.422 16.618,-16.467 15.968,-28.563 2.541,-15.704 13.387,-29.641 13.844,-45.031 -1.976,-20.752 -3.364,-45.581 -25.531,-56 -11.977,-15.189 -31.207,-15.337 -47.687,-21.5 -10.369,-2.814 -0.903,1.437 -3.719,2.375 -12.38,-1.789 -21.758,-1.982 -35.407,-1.469 -12.442,-4.391 -18.701,8.746 -20.374,20.375 -5.962,5.443 -4.392,16.716 -11.063,6.094 -14.479,6.324 -15.89,-22.296 -31.5,-12.906 1.74,-6.802 12.486,-16.056 18.906,-24.5 12.081,-7.246 19.466,-18.211 14.094,-32.625 -6.457,-19.791 -11.577,-40.5 -30.844,-48.032 -6.246,-11.263 -17.812,-11.773 -25.531,-22.937 -2.596,-13.708 -13.622,-7.666 -23.062,-7.687 -7.082,7.499 -12.58,-1.789 -18.094,-1.126 -11.753,5.99 -7.362,-3.558 2.312,-4.124 11.586,10.712 29.599,-9.068 38.5,3.5 6.936,10.194 16.961,15.179 28.219,10.812 11.387,-0.793 4.115,16.889 8.75,9.125 0.401,-15.713 -15.652,-27.757 -22.406,-41.5 -10.215,-13.228 -22.637,-42.254 0.531,-48.406 -3.99,-6.904 -22.855,-5.132 -18.969,-16.157 -12.542,-4.642 -14.465,-15.035 -18.156,-26.531 -6.601,-8.551 -7.171,-20.431 -19.375,-22.75 -11.36,-12.949 -28.921,-12.17 -42.125,-21.281 -10.012,-8.367 -5.252,7.58 -13.063,2.156 4.21,-5.875 -1.525,-10.674 2.313,-15.375 -16.095,-7.608 -16.76,-28.269 -19.031,-43.531 -5.541,-12.158 -11.619,-22.112 -15,-34.812 2.319,-10.191 -8.047,-18.249 -4.25,-28.813 -4.678,-7.871 -3.34,-16.035 -3,-25.375 -3.241,-10.267 -2.278,-19.36 -10.406,-26.62499 -8.87,-1.991 -5.763,0.192 -8.75,-6.813 -2.408,1.961 -8.124,0.299 -9.938,-7.562 -13.104,-11.924 -17.787,-33.814 -30.812,-41.406 -14.795,3.742 -25.819,-18.945 -38.75,-13.75 0.815,-13.714 -22.919,-15.59 -28.563,-6.656 0.311,8.906 -10.407,14.566 -19.156,15.5 -7.942,-5.526 -17.67,-5.525 -26.625,-6.657 -9.514,-0.637 -21.069,-5.09 -32.032,-5.093 -15.195,-2.764 4.596,-13.047 11.469,-4.282 12.319,9.869 21.421,-5.606 34.5,-3.594 2.331,-11.257 13.76,-19.676 23.375,-26.906 12.279,6.456 25.59,0.281 34.25,-10.25 3.82,-12.754 -19.157,-9.139 -22.312,-18.094 -1.327,-0.663 6.583,-16.508 -5.094,-15.812 -11.448,3.143 -22.728,12.058 -34.688,17.094 -9.734,3.015 -13.584,-1.858 -1.718,-1.906 9.232,-11.755 22.848,-18.099 36.031,-16.969 6.811,-5.119 15.45,3.454 16.906,-6.813 7.998,-6.672 25.583,-14.419 20.657,-25.844 7.201,-6.67 6.451,-10.777 8.718,-20.5 8.056,-5.579 20.206,-16.754 23.438,-29.843 -4.363,-15.124 14.053,-26.073 11.718,-39.781 -5.023,-21.756 18.532,-42.298 25.532,-55.344 7.708,-4.548 -0.903,-10.178 4.344,-11.875 -6.673,-5.188 -3.854,-17.626 -7.563,-21.781 -7.224,-9.396 -14.039,-14.282 -25.75,-14.25 -6.507,6.255 -15.002,1.977 -21.687,2 -11.279,7.351 -28.604,-1.14 -41.688,-0.469 -9.471,-3.958 -17.792,-4.367 -25.812,2.219 -18.437,3.087 -39.228,-20.706 -53.282,-0.313 -10.697,2.022 -21.463,3.069 -29.156,13.031 -5.687,5.903 -32.483,-2.34 -22.75,6.282 -5.853,5.384 -11.872,17.54 -21.125,13.124 9.428,-6.029 -6.596,-11.985 4.625,-9.218 2.983,-4.698 9.717,-4.669 10.625,-11.032 5.351,-6.642 13.882,-18.409 0.156,-10.624 -9.993,-3.253 -19.176,0.35 -26.812,11.312 -9.958,12.372 -8.113,-0.862 1.219,-5.594 3.334,-11.95 15.88,-6.277 22.874,-14.562 6.409,-7.169 11.947,-3.834 10.157,4.937 9.078,-6.333 16.115,-18.508 23.031,-28.469 2.577,-12.854 -4.138,2.609 -8.906,2.876 -10.526,3.901 -1.507,-0.03 -7.813,-3.032 -7.406,4.636 -20.263,3.714 -24.593,-4.218 7.318,2.615 19.319,1.997 20.187,-6.063 -2.06,-8.317 2.083,-15.851 12.031,-19 4.163,-8.111 12.019,-13.254 20.032,-19.313 12.902,-8.087 22.123,-21.109 30.843,-33.468 15.716,-5.033 27.298,-15.617 31.594,-31.344 8.466,-9.87 -2.216,-5.83 -6.781,-9.125 -3.177,-11.249 11.036,-19.264 10.937,-29.937 -6.091,-3.285 -15.317,0.61 -22.187,-2.75 -5.905,4.823 -11.771,-3.067 -14.75,-2.876 z"
     style="fill:#FFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3" />
</svg>
```

You can see the path has `id="britain"`, and in my Javascript snippet I reference that to change the fill colour.